# Items left to right within separate rows

Tags: html, css

I want to have multiple rows of data; the attached picture shows 3 representative rows.  On each row, there is a potential spacer that will shift the text of that row to the right.  It needs to be its own div, not a margin-left, because the spacer will have attributes unique from the text element (e.g. border-left, background-color, etc.).  Likewise, the div with text needs to be a div, as it can likewise have attributes.  The box with the div also may have text that exceeds the bounds of the containing box (as seen on row 3 above).

[image]

I have tried `float:left`, but I can't figure out where to clear the float so that there are rows (it just floats everything on the page).  I have also tried `display:inline-block`, but can't figure it out.

Here is the basic HTML.  I have tried many, many different CSS arrangements, and I think somebody starting from scratch would be better.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text" style="width:500px;">Row one text</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="spacer" style="width:500px;">Row two spacer</div>
    <div class="text" style="width:200px;>Row 2 text</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="spacer" style="width:700px;">Row three spacer</div>
    <div class="text" style="width:100px;">Row 3 text overflowing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So would this be sort of what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/maq0dL75/? Bearing in mind that the use of `grid-template-columns: subgrid` (currently) requires Firefox, which is one of the issues (though it can be worked around by placing the `grid-template-columns` styling on the `.row` elements themselves).

Comment: The code is generated dynamically, so preset column widths like `grid-template-columns: 500px 200px 100px;` would not work.  The spacer width is generated through a series of loops, and does not align to set columns, so it is not really a grid or table.

Comment: Can you post enough of your code to show how your rows and columns - and their contents - are generated?

Comment: It is just a recursive `for` loop that outputs a row and checks for children, if their are children, then it repeats the function for each child.  Output is 50 to 1000 rows of data, not unlike the above.  By the end there will be many different children>gchildren>ggchildren and so forth, each with a different spacer width.  In some ways it ends up looking like a file manager tree structure, though spacer widths are quite random (according to DNA haplotree mutations).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but if you just want something like that in the image with spaces and everything I recommend using [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I have recreated the code, tell me if you have any problem with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .item {
        flex: 0 32%;
        height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 2%; /* (100-32*3)/2 */
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .itemSec {
        font-size: 15px;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">
        first
        <div class="itemSec">column add text</div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        second
        <div class="itemSec">column add text</div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        third
        <div class="itemSec">column add text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you run that code you will see that it definitely does not create the desired rows, instead it creates columns.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add a `<div>` to each row that cleared the `float:left`, such as:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text" style="width:500px; float:left;">Row one text</div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="spacer" style="width:500px; height:25px; float:left;">Row two spacer</div>
    <div class="text" style="width:200px; float:left;">Row 2 text</div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="spacer" style="width:700px; height:25px; float:left;">Row three spacer</div>
    <div class="text" style="width:100px; height:25px; float:left;">Row 3 text overflowing</div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
```

It's not exactly elegant, but it gets the job done.

The overflowing text works through the following CSS:

```
.text { white-space: nowrap; }
```